# prime ideals, ring

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> If $ab \in 6\mathbb{Z}$, it does not follow that $a$ or $b$ is in $6\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> For example, $2 \cdot 3 = 6 \in 6\mathbb{Z}$, but $2$ nor $3$ is in $6\mathbb{Z}$.

Can someone explain why? Why is $2$ or $3$ not contained in the ideal $6\mathbb{Z}$, as it divides both of them?

Comment: Can you find an integer $n$ such that $6n=2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
6\mathbb{Z}=\{...,6\cdot\pm2,6\cdot\pm1,6\cdot\pm0,6\cdot\pm1,6\cdot\pm2,...\}=\{...,-12,-6,0,6,12,...\}
$$

so $2,3\not\in6\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you! I think I completely misunderstood @Belgi.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a definition. $6\mathbb{Z}=\{6n \colon n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. What integer $n$ gives $6n=2$?